# How to identify the name of selected TreeNode whether a namespace or a class?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am making a windows forms application. I am using a TreeView to display the Namespaces.

```
        var namespaces = assembly.GetTypes()
            .ToLookup(ns => ns.Namespace);


        foreach (var subNamespace in namespaces)
        {
            TreeNode assemblyNode = multiSelectMethodTree.Nodes
                                             .Add(subNamespace.Key);                
        }
```

Since there is a huge number of Methods and Classes in the project, I thought of displaying the classes only when the user clicks to expand('+') a namespace, and display methods when a class is expanded.

```
    private void MultiSelectMethodTree_AfterExpand(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode expandedNode = e.Node;
    }
```

In the AfterExpand event, I am not able to identify whether it is a namespace or a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could inherit from `TreeNode` class to create specific types each for Namespace, Class, Enum etc.

### Example:

```
public class NamespaceTreeNode : TreeNode { /* May add suited properties. */ }
```

And instead of creating `TreeNode` object, create an object of these types.

To identify which node is selected, you can do following:

```
private void MultiSelectMethodTree_AfterExpand(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode expandedNode = e.Node;

    if(expandedNode is NamespaceTreeNode) { /* TODO */ }
}
```